# JSON object property is "undefined" when dynamically reached

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm importing a JSON to my JS but I'm having some problems when trying to reach its properties by using **obj [varWithPropName]**.

However, it works when using **obj ["PropName"]**.

Follows a simplified snipped, hope it helps!

```
import * as CharInfo from '../Configs/CharInfo.json';
(...)
this.ID = "Maya";

console.log("Maya" === this.ID); //true

console.log(typeof(CharInfo)); //object

console.log(CharInfo["Maya"]); //{configs: {…}, animations: {…}}

console.log(CharInfo[this.ID]); //undefined
```

This is not a "console" related problem since when used outside the console.log it breaks in runtime,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'animations' of undefined
```

Although It works this way,

```
CharInfo.default[this.ID]; //{configs: {…}, animations: {…}}
```

I would like to understand why this happens before using some turnaround because I didn't find someone with the same problem :) thank you!

Comment: why don't you declare the ID the usual way? let/var/const?

Comment: This is just a simplified code snipped from the inside of the class constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the issue for you

> import CharInfo from '../Configs/CharInfo.json'

The issue will be that you are exporting the JSON in the file CharInfo.json as default. Something like:

```
json = { /* your json */ };
export default json;
```

At the time of import, you have imported like

```
`import * as CharInfo...`
```

which imports everything present in the file into a new variable CharInfo and the default export json is present as default inside the CharInfo object.

So, the actual json is now available as CharInfo.default.

If you import like `import CharInfo from '../Configs/CharInfo.json'` you will get the json inside CharInfo and CharInfo[this.ID] will work fine.

Hope it helps, revert for any issues.